# My silver body is not appearing

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```css
    body{background-color:#0BC;}

    .fixed-nav-bar{position: fixed;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      z-index:9999;
      width:100%;
      height:auto;
      text-align: center;
      background-color:#FFF;}

    /*display the text on the same line*/
       #topnav li{display:inline;list-style-type:none;padding:20px}

    /*removes underline format*/
       #topnav a{text-decoration:none;color:#00F;padding:5px;}

    /*set hover effect*/
       #topnav a:hover{background-color:blue;color:#FFF;}

    /*set background of about-box*/
       .silver-background{background-color:silver;}

    /*create a bottom bar*/
       .bottom-bar {width:fluid;
       padding:20px;
       bottom:0;
       left:0;
       right:0;
       position:absolute;
       height:50px;
       text-align:center;
       background-color:#FFF;}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster"   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <nav class="fixed-nav-bar" id="topnav">
     <ul>
      <p style="font-family:Lobster;font-size:30px;text">Stark</p>
        <li><a href="top">About</li>
        <li><a href="Portfolio">Portfolio</li>
        <li><a href="Contact">Contact</li>
     </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="silver-background">
     <p>This is a column for personal background</p>
    </div>  
  
    <div class="bottom-bar">
     <p>stark copyright 2016. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>
```

I intended to create a webpage with div elements for the body. Using the above codes, I have managed to create top and bottom bars. However, the "silver-background" is not coming out. Need some guidance here.

Update: The issue on `position:fixed` has been raised by many users here. While I appreciate the comments and understood the issue causing the body not appearing, I would like to note that the intention of putting the position fixed is because I want to have a top menu bar to be always appearing on screen while scrolling. If anyone is willing to provide any advice on how to retain it while fixing the body issue, I would be grateful.

Comment: How about using [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) (`F12` key) or the like, to see what's going on?

Comment: You can't put body tag inside a div

Comment: Have tried switching to `p` element, and nothing changed.

Comment: This is what seems to be causing the issue     .fixed-nav-bar {position: fixed}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```css
body{
  background-color:#0BC;
}

.fixed-nav-bar{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:999;
  width:100%;
 
  text-align: center;
  background-color:#FFF;
  position: fixed;
}

/*display the text on the same line*/
#topnav li{
  display:inline;
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:10px;
}

/*removes underline format*/
#topnav a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#54d;
  padding:5px;
}

/*set hover effect*/
#topnav a:hover{
  background-color:blue;
  color:#FFF;
}

/*set background of about-box*/
.silver-background{
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding:20px;
  background-color:silver;
  min-height:500px;
  text-align:center;
}

/*create a bottom bar*/
.bottom-bar {
  width:fluid;
  padding:20px;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  position:relative;
  height:50px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#FFF;}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster"   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div>
<nav class="fixed-nav-bar" id="topnav">
     <ul>
      <p style="font-family:Lobster;font-size:30px;text">Stark</p>
        <li><a href="top">About </a></li>
        <li><a href="Portfolio">Portfolio </a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact">Contact </a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
    

    <div class="silver-background">
     <p>This is a column for personal background</p>
    </div>  
  
    <div class="bottom-bar">
     <p>stark copyright 2016. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<nav>` element has `position: fixed;` and a high z-index. It is manually positioned in the same place as the silver `<div>` and raised above it.

There are several ways to stop this: you can turn off the background-color in the `<nav>`, so the elements behind it show through.

You can lower the z-index, though take note that the z-index is already naturally too high, so you can't just turn it off, you would have to set it down low; `-1` works.

You can remove the `fixed` positioning, although this messes the layout up too.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `position: absolute;` from  `.fixed-nav-bar` css class

**HTML**

```
<nav class="fixed-nav-bar" id="topnav">
  <ul>
    <p style="font-family:Lobster;font-size:30px;text">Stark</p>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="silver-background">
  This is a column for personal background
</div>

<div class="bottom-bar">
  <p>stark copyright 2016. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
   background-color: #0BC;
 } 

 .fixed-nav-bar {
   //position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   z-index: 9999;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #FFF;
 }
 /*display the text on the same line*/

 #topnav li {
   display: inline;
   list-style-type: none;
   padding: 20px
 }
 /*removes underline format*/

 #topnav a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #00F;
   padding: 5px;
 }
 /*set hover effect*/

 #topnav a:hover {
   background-color: blue;
   color: #FFF;
 }
 /*set background of about-box*/

 #silver-background {
   background-color: silver;
 }
 /*create a bottom bar*/

 .bottom-bar {
   width: fluid;
   padding: 20px;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   position: absolute;
   height: 50px;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #FFF;
   color: blue
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys I realized that the grey box is not appearing because I did not define the margin, causing it to be covered by the header. Problem solved. Thanks guys for helping!